# how to rectify errors in mysql php update?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Trying to add, update and delete in database table. but with this code i am able to add and delete the table, but the table is not updating, need to find errors.

using form to post the data and table to show the categories for user. update command is not showing results even not updating database table.

```
 <?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/thelewala/core/init.php';
    include 'includes/head.php';
    include 'includes/navigation.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 0";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    $errors = array();
    $category = '';
    $post_parent = '';

    // Edit Categories
    if(isset($_GET['edit']) && !empty($_GET['edit'])){
        $edit_id = (int)$_GET['edit'];
        $edit_id = sanitize($edit_id);
        $edit_sql = "SELECT * FROM  categories WHERE id = '$edit_id'";
        $edit_result = $db->query($edit_sql);
        $edit_category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_result);
    }

    // delete $category
    if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
        $delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete'];
        $delete_id = sanitize($delete_id);
    // this code is to delete parent category with their child category
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($category['parent'] == 0){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE parent ='$delete_id'";
        $db->query($sql);
    }
    // otherwise this code will delete selected child category
    $dsql = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = '$delete_id'";
    $db->query($dsql);
    header('Location: categories.php');
    }

    // Process form //
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
        $post_parent = sanitize($_POST['parent']);
        $category = sanitize($_POST['category']);
        $sqlform = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category ='$category' AND parent = '$post_parent'";
        if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
            $id = $edit_category['id'];
            $sqlform = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category ='$category' AND parent = '$post_parent' AND id != '$id'";
        }
        $fresult = $db->query($sqlform);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($fresult);

        // if category is blank //
        if($category == ''){
            $errors[] .= 'The category cannot be blank.';
        }
        // if exists in database-->
        if($count > 0){
            $errors[] .=$category. ' already exits. Please choose anather one.';
        }
        // display errors and update database-->
        if(!empty($errors)){
        // display errors-->
        $display = display_errors($errors); ?>
        <script>
        jQuery('document').ready(function(){
            jQuery('#errors').html('<?=$display; ?>');
        });
        </script>
        <?php
        }else{
        // update database-->
        $updatesql = "INSERT INTO categories (category, parent) VALUES ('$category','$post_parent')";
        if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
            $updatesql = "UPDATE categories SET category = '$category' parent = '$post_parent' WHERE id = '$edit_id'";
        }
        $db->query($updatesql);
        header('Location: categories.php');
        }
    }

    $category_value = '';
    $parent_value = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
        $category_value = $edit_category['category'];
        $parent_value = $edit_category['parent'];
    }else{
        if(isset($_POST)){
            $category_value = $category;
            $parent_value = $post_parent;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <h2 class="text-center">Categories</h2>

    <!-- form to add catagories-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <legend><?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'Edit':'Add A');?> Catagory</legend>
        <div id="errors"></div>
        <form class="form" action="categories.php<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'?edit='.$edit_id:'');?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="parent">Parent</label>
                <select class="form-group" name="parent" id="parent">
                    <option value="0"<?=(($parent_value ==0)?' selected="selected"':'');?>>Parent</option>
                    <?php while($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
                    <option value="<?=$parent['id']; ?>"<?=(($parent_value == $parent['id'])?' selected="selected"':'');?>><?=$parent['category']; ?></option>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Catagory</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category" name="category" value="<?=$category_value;?>">
                <input type="submit" value="<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'Edit':'Add');?> Category" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--table for categories chart-->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <th>Catagory</th><th>Parent</th><th></th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 0";
            $result = $db->query($sql);

          while($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
          $parent_id = (int)$parent['id'];
          $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = '$parent_id'";
          $cresult = $db->query($sql2);
          ?>
            <tr class="bg-primary">
              <td><?=$parent['category'];?></td>
              <td>Parent</td>
              <td>
                <a href="categories.php?edit=<?=$parent['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-secondary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</a>
                <a href="categories.php?delete=<?=$parent['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php while($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cresult)): ?>
            <tr class="table-info">
              <td><?=$child['category'];?></td>
              <td><?=$parent['category'];?></td>
              <td>
                <a href="categories.php?edit=<?=$child['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-secondary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</a>
                <a href="categories.php?delete=<?=$child['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    include 'includes/footer.php';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your SQL query.

```
$updatesql = "UPDATE categories SET category = '$category', parent = '$post_parent' WHERE id = '$edit_id'";
```

You just needed to add a comma after '$category'.